# How do I hide the name of my page but keep the dynamically created page title

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL:
www.mysite/apage.php?product_id=295-Product-name-in-a-color

I would like the following:

www.mysite/id=295-Product-name-in-color

The product name and colour are triggered from a different page.

I can redirect the actual apage.php  using .htaccess however I lose everything else and it won't find my page.

Any help welcome

Comment: Use [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html), if you don't have an Apache, what else do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^id=([^/]+)-(.+)$ /apage.php?product_id=$1-$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```